# XDM could not download the file as server sent an invalid response

Tags: 20.04, downloads, youtube, download-manager

I am using XDM ([Xtreme Download Manager](https://xtremedownloadmanager.com/), a file downloader) for many years, specially for YT since it catch and download YT videos directly (**without using another website to give DL of YT videos**). Recently, I got this error message (in the image below), and I can't download videos directly from YT anymore.

[Picture of the XDM error message](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/8551323/175474425-2eb5ed09-d7fb-4985-afd7-27c8d9444d70.png)

How to solve this problem ?

**N.B**, I have Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS, and XDM works well and downloads any Direct Link, but it is not the case in YT. I am using a third-party website to give DL of YT videos that will be downloaded then by XDM.

Comment: You've not provided any release details, but `xdm` in Ubuntu refers to the X Display Manager (https://packages.ubuntu.com/kinetic/xdm for the latest Lubuntu release for example).  I use Lubuntu & haven't noticed any issues with `youtube-dl` of late so why not use that?  Please provide release details, and if using non-Ubuntu software providing a link to where it's from can be helpful especially when it *conflicts* in name to Ubuntu software using that identical name (XDM is the X11 Display Manager having been so since 1989 which is years before google).

Comment: @guiverc Thank you to point that out. In my case, `XDM` is for Xtreme Download Manager. The feature that I like the most in `XDM` is the pop-up "Download" button when playing videos, so no need to copy/paste URLs, I don't know if `youtube-dl` has similar feature ?

Comment: I still don't see any Lubuntu release details...

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS not Lubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no answers, and even after many attempts of searching over other websites, I decided to switch to **yt-dl** (Thank you @guiverc).

I am using currently [**yt-dlp**](https://github.com/yt-dlp/yt-dlp) (the ameliorated version of yt-dl) without GUI (I think there are versions of yt-dlp with GUI), and honestly, it's the right tool in the right place, it has many features that don't exist in XDM, and more importantly, the downloading speed is high and better.

**1.** To install it:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yt-dlp/stable
sudo apt update
sudo apt install yt-dlp
```

**2.** To show the video qualities available to download:

```
yt-dlp -F [URL_of_youtube_video]
```

**3.** To download a **720p** (or **360p**) video:

```
yt-dlp -f 22 (or 18) [URL_of_youtube_video]
```

**4.** You can also download any YT playlist, and resume after the interruption, the following command is very useful:

```
yt-dlp -ciw [URL_of_youtube_playlist]
```

or

```
yt-dlp -ciw [ID_of_youtube_playlist]
```

- `-i` ,   `--ignore-errors` : Continue on download errors, for example to skip unavailable videos in a playlist
- `-w` , `--no-overwrites`  : Do not overwrite files
- `-c` ,  `--continue`   : Force resume of partially downloaded files.

(Source: [yt-dlp](https://github.com/yt-dlp/yt-dlp))

---

May be you will face an error about "**brotli**", just install it:

```
sudo apt install python3-brotli
```